# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection when routing with additional controller in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I got this error-->'NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161'..When i try to call my additional controller in laravel 5.2..Already I  did php artisan serve to activate localhost:8000..can you please explain the basic layout of routing with controller in laravel?

Comment: Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing

Comment: Route::resource('itemCRUD', 'ItemCRUDController');  I have written like this..this is okai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NotFoundHttpException occurs when no given route is matched to your given request to a certain endpoint/url.

Make sure you are sending the request to the correct url which is correctly defined in your routes.php (web.php for laravel 5.3+) with it's correct verb, (GET, POST, PATCH, etc).

Basic flow goes like this:

In your routes.php, you'd define a route like:

```
Route::get("/users", "UsersController@show");
```

then in your Http folder define that given controller with it's name which you referred in above call and anything proceeding @ symbol is a callback function which gets called automatically.

So in your http/UsersController.php, you'd have:

```
public function show(Request $request) {
    //Do something with your request.
    return "Something"; //could be an array or string or 
    //whatever since laravel automatically casts it into JSON,
    //but it's strongly recommended to use transformers and compact method.
}
```

For more information try looking at laravel docs, they provide an amazing way to get started tutorial.  [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2)